# Updating a column in a table with a pl/sql anonymous block

Tags: oracle, plsql

Below insert code works fine at SQL developer but failed in sql plus.

```
create table abc(metric varchar2(10), line number(2), text varchar2(2000));

insert into abc
(metric, line, text) 
values('abc', 1, q'#declare
    k_sid       constant varchar2(100) := upper(sys_context('USERENV', 'DB_NAME'));    
    -- Cusor-FOR-loop over all spy_configs for k_sme ...
    for r_stmt in (select k_sid as instance
                         ,k_sme as metric
                         ,key
                         ,value
                         ,'ERROR - spfile-parameter: '||key||' must be set to: '||value||' but is not - please check and change it !!!' as text
                   from bmw_system.bmw_spy_conf 
    raise_application_error (-20001, ' - '||sqlcode||' - '||sqlerrm,true);
end;#')
```

Is there any solution through sql plus parameter.Any pointer will be greatly appreciated.

REgards,
Sandeep

Comment: "failed in sql plus" eh?

Comment: one option is to save the commands in a file and use sql plus to execute the sql from a file: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/script.php

Comment: I've never seen the `q'#....#'` string format shown in the INSERT value list used before.

Comment: @BobJarvis It's called the "alternative quoting mechanism" and is really useful if your string contains single quotes (esp. for dynamic SQL). You don't have to use # as delimiter, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm

Comment: @FrankSchmitt - I get to learn something new every day. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
set sqlt /
insert into abc
(metric, line, text) 
values('abc', 1, q'[declare
    k_sid       constant varchar2(100) := upper(sys_context('USERENV', 'DB_NAME'));    
    -- Cusor-FOR-loop over all spy_configs for k_sme ...
    for r_stmt in (select k_sid as instance
                         ,k_sme as metric
                         ,key
                         ,value
                         ,'ERROR - spfile-parameter: '||key||' must be set to: '||value||' but is not - please check and change it !!!' as text
                   from bmw_system.bmw_spy_conf 
    raise_application_error (-20001, ' - '||sqlcode||' - '||sqlerrm,true);
end;]')
/
set sqlt ;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch12040.htm#i2498515

> **SET SQLT[ERMINATOR] {; | c | ON | OFF}**
>
> Sets the character used to end script or data entry for PL/SQL blocks or SQL statements, to execute the script, and to load it into the buffer.
>
> It cannot be an alphanumeric character or a whitespace. OFF means that SQL*Plus recognizes no command terminator; you terminate a SQL command by entering an empty line or a slash (/). If SQLBLANKLINES is set ON, you must use the BLOCKTERMINATOR to terminate a SQL command. ON resets the terminator to the default semicolon (;).

Answer (score 0):

Save your commands into a sql file and then execute the file from SQL Plus: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/script.php

```
SQL > @{path}{file}
```